# What sorting algorithm does Rust's built-in `sort` use?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, rust

What algorithm is the [built-in `[T]::sort` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort) using? Is it possible to have a look at the code for that method?

Comment: Sure. [`slice::sort` is merge sort](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/slice.rs.html#206-210), and [`slice::sort_unstable` is quicksort](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/mod.rs.html#1501-1505).

Comment: In case you have not yet realized, right next each item in the documentation is a `[src]` text. It's actually a link taking you straight to the source code for said item.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As per documentation:

[`sort`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort):

> #### Current implementation
>
> The current algorithm is an adaptive, iterative merge sort inspired by [**timsort**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). It is designed to be very fast in cases where the slice is nearly sorted, or consists of two or more sorted sequences concatenated one after another.
>
> Also, it allocates temporary storage half the size of self, but for short slices a non-allocating insertion sort is used instead.

As for the rest of the standard library and the entire compiler, the source is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/5f60208ba11171c249284f8fe0ea6b3e9b63383c/src/liballoc/slice.rs#L841-L980).

[`sort_unstable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_unstable):

> #### Current implementation
>
> The current algorithm is based on [**pattern-defeating quicksort**](https://github.com/orlp/pdqsort) by Orson Peters, which combines the fast average case of randomized quicksort with the fast worst case of heapsort, while achieving linear time on slices with certain patterns. It uses some randomization to avoid degenerate cases, but with a fixed seed to always provide deterministic behavior.
>
> It is typically faster than stable sorting, except in a few special cases, e.g. when the slice consists of several concatenated sorted sequences.

The source is also [available on GitHub](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/5f60208ba11171c249284f8fe0ea6b3e9b63383c/src/libcore/slice/sort.rs).

(emphasis are mine)

Answer (score 2):

The standard answer is, I think, Read The Fine Manual ;-)

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#current-implementation-3

And yes, it is possible to have a look at the code, by clicking on the `src` link on the right of every documented item. For the `sort` method, this leads to:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/slice.rs.html#206-210

It uses a private `merge_sort` function which is defined here:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/slice.rs.html#888-990